# How to set soap:address dynamically based on maven profile

Tags: web-services, maven, soap, wsdl, cxf

Currently in my wsdl file i have the following address which points to dev box.

```
<wsdl:service name="SecurityTokenService">
    <wsdl:port name="STS_Port" binding="tns:UT_Binding">
        <soap:address location="http://DEVbox:8080/DoubleItSTS/STS" />
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

I would like to read from maven profile and dynamically set soap:address property so i dont have to change code every time i deploy to QA or Production boxes. Is there any way this can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, try the [maven velocity plugin](http://code.google.com/p/velocity-maven-plugin/wiki/HowToUseThePlugin). You can build your WSDL from a template, and inject in URL's varying on your profile.

Comment: @TastyCode, are you able to fix this issue? I am facing the same problem